# factory method to create widget in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, factory

should you create a factory method to create `tkinter` widgets or is it considered best practice not to?

for example a program with say 10 entry boxes, 5 buttons, and 16 labels (just random numbers) would have 31 occurences of pretty much the same code most commonly like this:

```
self.a_widget = ttk.widget_type(self,text="hello world!")
self.a_widget.config(foreground="white",background="black")
self.a_widget.config(font=("Calibri",15,"bold"))
self.a_widget.pack()
```

so creating a factory method for this could be fairly straight forward and would certainly prevent having nearly the same code over and over.

would doing so be beneficial for future use or is something like this discouraged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go ahead and do it. Abstracting out repetitive behavior follows the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself), and there's nothing special about Tkinter that disqualifies the practice from being used here.

Comment: `tkinter` was just an example

Comment: Following the DRY principle is also good even when not using Tkinter.

Answer (score 1):

If using a factory makes the code less complex and easier to understand, then yes, use a factory.